# Organize GraphQL files in directories in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

Upon running `rails g graphql:install`, a set of useful base type files are created in `/app/graphql/types` for us to extend when defining our own types. When running any of the generators, it creates these files in the same folder also. I set about creating sub directories thinking I could add some sense to this giant catch-all directory, but couldn't get things to load properly.

Since there is a base file for each type (`base_enum.rb`, `base_object.rb`, etc.), I created a folder for extensions of each of these types (`enum_types`, `object_types`, etc.). This broke auto loading though and I had to explicitly import these files to be able to use these custom types. So, at the top of `query_type.rb`, `mutation_type.rb` and `app/graphql/mutations/base_mutation.rb` I added the following:

```
['enum_typs', 'input_object_types', 'interface_types', 'object_types', 'scalar_types', 'union_types'].each do |dir|
  Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/#{dir}/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
end
```

This allowed things to run, but any change would break auto loading so I would have to restart the server on each change. I started reading through [this article about auto loading on the rails site](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html), but it was quite honestly a little over my head. Though it led me to believe I had to either find the correct names for my folders or namespace the objects defined in my type definition files properly to be able to do this.

Is there a sane way to organize these files in sub-directories which doesn't break auto loading? Do most projects just have a flat folder structure for these files?

Thank you!